# Logical order in R to create column in data frame and fill it with information

Tags: r, dataframe, scatter-plot

I've got a df with the following column among others (with superpopulations ID). it's colname is Superpop:

```
EUR
EUR
EUR
AMR
AMR
AFR
AMR
AFR
EUR
SAS
EUR
...
```

and I need (for later using scatterplot3d) to build another column, let's say the column named ¨pcolors¨, which has to have color names to identify the superpopulations to color the points in the plot. I want this as an output:

```
EUR red
EUR red
EUR red
AMR blue
AMR blue
AFR green
AMR blue
AFR green
EUR red
SAS yellow
EUR red
... ...
```

the thing is that they aren't sorted, and the df is 2524 lines long, so i can't do it manually and i would prefer not to sort it because of the order of the other columns. Is there a way, for instance, with a logical function to say ¨generate another column, and , if in that line Superpop==EUR, then write ¨red¨ at that line in pcolor column...¨ and so on for the 5 superpopulations i've got ? Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps creating a look-up table with your ID and associated color first, then merge the table to your original data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is pretty simple:

```
pcolors <- unsplit(superpop, value = colors())
```

You can pick the colors you want in the value-parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Just use subscripting. You can create a named-vector of colors like this:

```
pcolor <- c(EUR = "red", AMR = "blue", AFR = "green", SAS = "yellow")
```

then if

```
df <- data.frame(Superpop = c("EUR","EUR","EUR","AMR","AMR","AFR","AMR","AFR","EUR","SAS","EUR"))
```

if you just do

```
df$color = pcolor[as.character(df$Superpop)]
```

Then `df` is:

```
Superpop  color
1       EUR    red
2       EUR    red
3       EUR    red
4       AMR   blue
5       AMR   blue
6       AFR  green
7       AMR   blue
8       AFR  green
9       EUR    red
10      SAS yellow
11      EUR    red
```

Comment: Thank you ! Good answer, but I used the one of Majo's because it was shorter and did the trick :) . But now I have two ways

Comment: @melunuge92 I also learned something from Majo's answer. In R there are typically several ways to achieve the same goal.